# Django model ordering based on returned value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model as follows:

```
class LegalEntityOwn(models.Model): 
    # the fields 
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'legal_entity_own'
        ordering = [... the returned value defined by me below...]

    def __unicode__(self):
        if ....
            return x 
        else:
            return y
```

Basically, my question is stated in the code. I want to set the default order to be based what is defined in the **unicode** method. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this? The `__unicode__` method is for making a string representation of your object. It's not clear why you want to use that to determine ordering.

Comment: Yes, of course.  When the list of model objects is rendered in my Django form widget, I would like the combobox to be ordered by the options that the user sees in the combobox

Comment: Still not sure I understand, but in any case I don't think it is possible. `ordering` defines a database field that you want the database engine to order results by. The database has no knowledge of what you intend to do with that data. You would have to order manually in Python after fetching the results if you wanted to order based on some generated property like a string representation.

Comment: You cant use the `__unicode__` method for ordering. But you could read the value in the combobox, and in your view do `entities = LegalEntityOwn.objects.all().order_by(value_in_combo_box)`